# Reading electronics layout from the file

Tags: java

folks... I'm having some trouble with understanding how to read the file and stuck here. I have the following textfile:

```
IMPORT halfadder fulladder

    A0 A1 A2 A3 B0 B1 B2 B3 Cin -> S0 S1 S2 S3 Cout

    fulladder A0 B0 Cin -> C0 S0
    fulladder A1 B1 C0  -> C1 S1
    fulladder A2 B2 C1  -> C2 S2
    fulladder A3 B3 C2  -> Cout S3
```

When the Scanner sees the word `IMPORT` then the next one or two words are textfiles (in this case `halfadder` and `fulladder` are textfiles) which I have to read them too consequently. I don't need help with the whol algrorithm, I just need to know how to read the next one or two words-filenames after the word `IMPORT`. Could smb help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```
public Scanner getCircuitScanner(String circuitName) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner textfile = new Scanner(new File(circuitName));
        while(textfile.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = textfile.nextLine();
            if(line.contains("IMPORT"))
            {
                String nextToken = line.next();//halfadder
                Scanner textfile1 = new Scanner(new File(nextToken));//read halfadder textfile

            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking how to read IMPORT, halfadder and fulladder separately from the file instead of reading them together as a single line.

1. I suggest you should use  `textfile.useDelimiter(", *");` and once
   you are done reading file names, you can change it back as
   `useDelimiter("\n *");`
2. Or you could also simply split the string that you read each time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `split` method on the `line` that contains `IMPORT`:

```
    String line = textfile.nextLine();
    if(line.contains("IMPORT")) {
        String files = line.split("\s");
    }
```

Note that the first element in the array `files[0]` will contain `IMPORT`.

Comment: Why do you use an "ungreedy" regex? This simply boils down to `\s`, which means that if one uses two tabs, it will add an empty string.